# Using sets of Entity Framework entities at runtime

Tags: entity-framework

I have an EF6 setup against a sql server db with about 60 tables in it.
I have entities for each table. What i'm trying to do is run the same method against a set of these entities that will be known at runtime.
The method is a qa/qc routine that does some data check on particular fields that are assured to be in each table. 
I guess what i want to do is make the entity a parameter to the method so i can call it consecutive times.
I would also want to make a set of entities to pass as the parameter.
something like this:

```
     List<string> entList = new List<string>(){"Table1","Table2","Table3"}; 
     foreach (entName in entList)
{
//create an entity with the string name
//call myQAQCMethod with the entity
}

MyQAQCMethod (entity SomeEntity)
{
//run against this entity
doQAQC(SomeEntity);
}
```

Can this be done? Is it a job for reflection?

**EDIT**

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var results = context.EntityAs.Where(a => a.Prop1 == e.Prop1)
                                  .Where(a => a.Prop2 == e.Prop2)
                                  .Select(a => new
                                  {
                                      APropertyICareAbout = a.Prop1,
                                      AnotherPropertyICareAbout = a.Prop2
                                  }).ToArray();
}
```

is precisely want i want to do. The thing is I want to avoid typing this loop 60 times. I think i'm looking for a way to "feed" a set of entities to this single method. 
Also, thank you very much for helping me. I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to abstract an interface (entity framework won't even notice):

```
interface IQaQcable
{
    int CommonInt { get; set; }
    string CommonString { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA : IQaQcable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommonInt { get; set; }
    public string CommonString { get; set; }

    // other properties and relations
}

public class EntityB : IQaQcable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommonInt { get; set; }
    public string CommonString { get; set; }

    // other properties and relations
}

// in some unknown utility class
void MyQaQcMethod<T>(T entity) where T : IQaQcable
{
    doSomethingWithIQaQcableProperties(entity.CommonInt, entity.CommonString);
}

// in some unknown test class
void Test()
{
    var entities = new List<IQaQcable> { new EntityA(), new EntityB() };
    foreach (var e in entities)
        MyQaQcMethod(e);
}
```

Now, you could extract a base class from which each derives that actually implements the `CommonInt` and `CommonString` properties for each entity needing them, but that can get kind of tricky with Table-Per-Type/Table-Per-Hierarchy, so I'd start with this, and then consider introducing either an `abstract` or concrete base class as an improvement.

**EDIT**

Maybe your looking for something simpler than I first thought, based on your last comment.

Let's give ourselves what the `DbContext` for this might look like:

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; }
}
```

So, it could just be that you wish to do this:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var results = context.EntityAs.Where(a => a.Prop1 == e.Prop1)
                                  .Where(a => a.Prop2 == e.Prop2)
                                  .Select(a => new
                                  {
                                      APropertyICareAbout = a.Prop1,
                                      AnotherPropertyICareAbout = a.Prop2
                                  }).ToArray();
}
```

Keeping in mind, if there is some set of properties in common across entity classes, you could still do something like the following:

```
IEnumerable<T> MyQaQcMethod(IQueryable<T> entities, T referenceEntity) where T : IQaQcAble
{
    return entities.Where(e => SomePredicate(e, referenceEntity));
}

void Test()
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        // EntityA implements IQaQcAble
        var resultsForA = MyQaQcMethod(context.EntityAs, defaultEntity).ToArray();
        // so does EntityB, so can call with either
        var resultsForB = MyQaQcMethod(context.EntityBs, defaultEntity).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, to avoid modifying the generated entity classes, you could implement the `interface` members — and the `interface` — in a separate source file using `partial` classes. E.g.

```
// IQaQcAble.cs
internal interface IQaQcAble
{
    int CommonInt { get; set; }
    string CommonString { get; set; }
}

// a class whose existing property names match the interface
public partial class EntityA : IQaQcAble
{
    int IQaQcAble.CommonInt
    {
        get { return CommonInt; }
        set { CommonInt = value; }
    }
    string IQaQcAble.CommonString
    {
        get { return CommonString; }
        set { CommonString = value; }
    }
}

// a class whose property names differ
public partial class EntityB : IQaQcAble
{
    int IQaQcAble.CommonInt
    {
        get { return SomeOtherInt; }
        set { SomeOtherInt = value; }
    }
    string IQaQcAble.CommonString
    {
        get { return SomeOtherInt.ToString(); }
        set { SomeOtherInt = Convert.ToInt32(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally had a chance to look this over. Thank you for the suggestion. it is really cool. a few questions - 1)i'm modifying the generated EF code and won't that get wiped out if i regenerate my ef model from the database? 2) to extend your example code, when i get into MyQaQcMethod and i make reference to 'entity' i get access to the CommonInt property which is nice. But what i really need is access to the entity itself so i can write a lambda query against it.

Comment: i'm struggling to communicate what it is i'm trying to do. i'm trying to validate fields in these entities. so my qaqc method is like var q = db.ROUTES.Where(o => o.Route_ID == null); That works fine if i'm targeting one entity. But now i want to run that same check on 60 entities

Comment: in the code you suggested when i get to calling MyQaQcMethod(e) e is actually an object with default parameters. what i am looking for is the equivalent of db.EntityA so that i can then do .Where against it. I don't really want an actual entity i want the concept of an entity that i want to then fill via query. obviously i'm not getting the semantics correct. sorry about that.

Comment: i made an edit in my original question but, yes, your 'var results' is what i want. i just need to do that 60 times somehow.